# Finding a potential function for $\vec F=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\vec i+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\vec j$ on $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^2- \{(x,y)\,|\,y=0,\,x\geq0 \}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, differential-operators

In one of my Calculus III classes the professor presented the following vector field, defined on the set $S$ of all points $(x,y) \neq(0,0)$ :
$$
\bbox[6px,border:1px solid black] {
\vec{F}=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\vec{i} + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\vec{j}
}
$$

Although $\vec{F}$ is not a gradient on $S$, it is a gradient on the set $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^2-\left\{(x,y)\,|\,y=0, \, x\geq0\right\}$, i.e, all points in the xy-plane except those on the positive x-axis. In the class, my professor wrote a potential function for $\vec{F}$ on $\Omega$ using the following functions:

$$
\bbox[6px,border:1px solid black] {
\begin{alignat}{0}
\Psi_1(x,y)=-\arctan\left(\frac x y \right), \,y\neq0 &\text{and} &\Psi_2(x,y)=\arctan\left(\frac y x \right), \,x\neq0
\end{alignat}
}
$$

The first is a potential of $\vec F$ on $\Omega^+=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,y>0\}$ and on $\Omega^-=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,y<0\}$.

The last one is a potential of $\vec F$ too, but on $\Omega_+=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,x>0\}$ and on $\Omega_-=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,x<0\}$

**The potential function wrote by my professor:**
[image: Class Notes]
$$
\bbox[8px,border:1px solid black] {
\phi (x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\Psi_1(x,y) & \text{if $(x,y) \in R_1$} \\[2ex]
\Psi_2(x,y)+\frac\pi 2 & \text{if $(x,y) \in R_2$} \\[2ex]
\Psi_1(x,y)+2\pi & \text{if $(x,y) \in R_3$} \\
\end{cases}
}
$$
*(Note: I remember that my professor started with the argument that since $\nabla\Psi_1=\vec F = \nabla\Psi_2$, then $\Psi_1-\Psi_2=k, \,k \in \mathbb{R}$)*

---

**My doubts:**

- I've tried a lot, but still have not figured out how to build $\phi (x,y)$ using $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$. So, how to find this specific potential function of $\vec F$ ?
- Why can't I simply write potential functions of $\vec{F}$ in the following ways
  $$
  \phi_A (x,y) =
  \begin{alignat}{0}
  \begin{cases}
  \Psi_1(x,y) & \text{if $(x,y) \in R_1$} \\[2ex]
  \Psi_2(x,y) & \text{if $(x,y) \in R_2$} \\[2ex]
  \Psi_1(x,y) & \text{if $(x,y) \in R_3$} \\
  \end{cases}
  &\text{or}
  &\phi_B(x,y)=
  \begin{cases}
  \Psi_1(x,y) & \text{if $y>0$} \\[2ex]
  0 & \text{if $y=0$ and $x<0$} \\[2ex]
  \Psi_1(x,y) & \text{if $y<0$} \\
  \end{cases}
  \end{alignat}
  $$
  since $\nabla\phi_A=\nabla\phi_B=\vec F$ on $\Omega$ ?

Comment: Exactly how are $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$ defined?

Comment: Hint: What values do $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$ have on the four halfaxes? Are $\phi_A$ and $\phi_B$ continuous?

Comment: @md2perpe I'm not sure how to write these regions, but looking at the picture I think it's something like (for $R_1$):
$$
R_1=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \,|\,y=x \,\,\text{and}\,\,x\geq0  \,\,\text{and}\,\, y\neq 0 \cup\, 0 < y < -x \}
$$

Comment: @md2perpe But is it necessary to describe the regions in order to find $\phi (x,y)$?

Comment: Using polar coordinates $(r,\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is the counterclockwise angle from the positive x-axis, we have $\phi=\alpha - \pi/2$ on all of $\Omega.$ The need to split $\Omega$ into regions occurs when we want to express $\phi$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @md2perpe About $\phi_A$ and $\phi_B$, they aren't continuous, but they are piecewise continuous. Another thing: I remember that my professor started with the fact that $\Psi_1-\Psi_2=k,\, k \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Since they aren't continuous, they are not potentials for all of $\Omega$.

Comment: @md2perpe But isn't piecewise continuity enough? Consider the electric potential due to a point charge, for example: $V(\bf{r})$ $= \frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}$ is discontinuous at zero, but $\vec E = -\nabla V$.

Comment: In that case you have one patch covering all of the domain, which excludes origin.

Comment: When you need several patches, they should be defined on **open** regions, and where they overlap, they should be equal. Here, if we take the regions to be open and exclude the beams in dashed green, then they don't cover all of the domain $\Omega$.

Comment: @md2perpe So, I don't understand why $\phi_B$ isn't a potential of $\vec F$, because all the patches are defined on open regions.

Comment: The middle patch, $\phi_B(x,y) = 0$ if $y=0$ and $x<0$, is not defined on an open region.

Comment: @md2perpe You said that when I have several patches *"they should be defined on **open** regions"*. But why?

Comment: If I use this fact in the correct potential $\phi (x,y)$, $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$ must be open. So, $\phi (x,y)$ is not a potential of $\vec F$ because of the beams in dashed green.

Comment: The patches should be open because either the union of two patches will be disconnected or the two patches overlap. In the former case we will not have problems with discontinuity of the total potential. In the latter case the patches must be compatible (i.e. be equal on the overlapping region).

Comment: Do the beams in dashed green belong to the regions of which they are boundaries, i.e. the one with $y=-x$ belongs to $R_1$ and $R_2$, and the other to $R_2$ and $R_3$? If yes, then the professor has made an error with respect to the definition of patches. If no, then the patches will exclude the dashed green beams, but on this subdomain you can actually use $\phi_A$ as a potential.

Comment: But the most important thing is that the potential must be differentiable (and thus continuous) on the domain (here $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(x,0) \mid x \geq 0 \}$). And that is what the professor wants to do with his definition of $\phi$. His potential will be smooth even if the patches are not open.

Comment: @md2perpe I'm not sure. I think he didn't mention this. So, if the potential is piecewise defined, but differentiable on the entire domain, we can drop the condition that the regions should be open, right? If so, the potential that my professor wrote is right even if the beams in dashed green belong to the regions of which they are boundaries.

Comment: Yes. So his potential is differentiable, while yours are not even continuous. And using open patches is primarily a tool to simplify things in the theory.