# Is $\langle (-y)/(x^2+y^2),x/(x^2+y^2) \rangle$ a conservative vector field?

Tags: calculus

If it is,I found two potential function which is $\arctan(y/x)$ and $-\arctan(x/y)$.
But I don't know which is true.

Comment: Note that $\arctan(y/x)$ and $-\arctan(x/y)$ differ only by a piecewise constant function, so either works as a potential function (at least on a domain where the vector field doesn't blow up).

Comment: But I try to apply the gradient theorem to calculate the line integral,the curve from (-1,0)to(0,1),and the result is not the same (I got π and 0),I don't know why,thank you for your help.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3222768/168433

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly: no, it's not a conservative vector field on its entire domain $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$. The vectors of the vector field form counterclockwise circles about the origin, and the line integral of any counterclockwise circle about the origin is $2\pi$.

On any *simply connected* subset of its domain, however, the vector field is conservative. You can define a potential function as follows: pick an arbitrary point $p$ in the domain and let the potential at any point $x$ be the angle in radians from $p$ to $x$, where positive means you can get from $p$ to $x$ by moving counterclockwise *within the domain* and negative means moving clockwise. One possible choice of potential function is $\arctan(y/x)$, as long as the domain lies entirely in the first and fourth quadrants (otherwise there's a discontinuity associated with crossing the $y$-axis). Of course, it's not possible to define these potential functions unambiguously if the domain wraps all the way around the origin.